# What are super-translations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, physics, mathematical-physics

There's been a lot of news lately about a possible solution to the [black hole information paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_information_paradox) from a [presentation given by Stephen Hawking](http://www.washingtonpost.com/news/speaking-of-science/wp/2015/08/25/stephen-hawking-believes-hes-solved-a-huge-mystery-about-black-holes/) to the [KTH Royal Institute of Technology in Stockholm](https://www.kth.se/en/aktuellt/nyheter/hawking-offers-new-solution-to-black-hole-mystery-1.586546). Many of them mention the term *super translation*.

[This article](http://www.economist.com/blogs/economist-explains/2015/08/economist-explains-20?fsrc=scn/fb/wl/ee/st/stephenhawkingsansweraboutblackholes), for example, states (with emphasis added):

> His flash of inspiration came when listening to a lecture in April
>   about what are called **super-translations**, a bit of the heady
>   branch of mathematics known as group theory. Dr Hawking thinks that
>   incoming particles shed their information like a coat as they pass
>   into a black hole, leaving it draped on the event horizon itself.
>   **Super-translations** mathematically describe how that information influx can slightly jiggle the fabric of space at the horizon, in turn
>   shifting around when and how the black hole radiates.

What exactly are super-translations, mathematically?

I have been trying to search for this term online, but the results are flooded with news articles. Where can I find some sources that describe super-translations in greater detail?

**EDIT:** Another description of super-translations is provided in [a recent article](http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/dark-star-diaries/stephen-hawking-s-new-black-hole-paper-translated-an-interview-with-co-author-andrew-strominger/):

> The horizon of a black hole has the weird feature that it’s a sphere
>   and it’s expanding outward at the speed of light. For every point on
>   the sphere, there’s a light ray. So it’s composed of light rays. But
>   it doesn’t get any bigger and that’s because of the force of gravity
>   and the curvature of space. And, by the way, that’s why nothing that
>   is inside a black hole can get out—because the boundary of the black
>   hole itself is already moving at the speed of light.
>
> There’s this symmetry of a black hole that we all knew about in which
>   you move uniformly forward and backward in time along all of the light
>   rays. But there’s another symmetry, which is the new thing in this
>   paper (though various forms of it have been discussed elsewhere). It’s
>   a symmetry in which the individual light rays are moved up and down.
>   See, individual light rays can’t talk to each other—if you’re riding
>   on a light ray, causality prevents you from talking to somebody riding
>   on an adjacent light ray. So these light rays are not tethered
>   together. You can slide them up and down relative to one another. That
>   sliding is called a super-translation.
>
> And in a way, it looks like you're not doing anything. Think of a
>   bundle of infinitely long straws and you move one up and down relative
>   to the other. Are you doing anything, or not? What we showed is that
>   you are doing something. It turns out that adding a soft graviton has
>   an alternate description as a super-translation in which you move some
>   of these light rays back and forth relative to one another.
>
> That’s super-translations on black holes. Super-translations were
>   introduced in the 1960s, and they were talking not about the light
>   rays that comprise the boundary of spacetime at the horizon of a black
>   hole but the light rays that comprise the boundary of spacetime out at
>   infinity. The story started by analyzing those supertranslations.

Comment: I want to say "What you get when a regular translation is bitten by a radioactive grad student," but I don't *think* that's right...

Comment: Sabine Hoffsteder has some references to the literature on her [blogpost](http://backreaction.blogspot.com/2015/08/hawking-proposes-new-idea-for-how.html) about Hawking's recent work, which probably will lead you to the right direction. (Try searching for "BMS Supertranslations"; also see chapter 11 of Wald's *General Relativity*.)

Comment: Once the radioactive bite takes affect, the super-translation is strong enough to jiggle space fabric.  It uses this fabric to make a red pajama suit to wear as it swings between groups of buildings in an effort to defeat _Black Hole_.

Comment: Related Phys.SE post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/296189/2451

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A suprertranslation is a diffeomorphism on an asymptotically-flat Riemannian or pseudo-Riemannian manifold, such that the result is also asymptotically-flat. (The diffeomorphism doesn't need to be an isometry).
(Of course, I didn't define asymptotic-flattness. I don't know the definition, but do know that in an asymptotically-flat manifold if you go far-enough in any direction, the metric becomes close to being flat as you wish).
The group of suprertranslations of a certain manifold is called the BMS group, after Bondi,Van der Burg and Sachs who discussed them in the context of gravitational waves in the following papers:
*Bondi, Hermann, M. G. J. Van der Burg, and A. W. K. Metzner. "Gravitational waves in general relativity. VII. Waves from axi-symmetric isolated systems." Proceedings of the Royal Society of London A: Mathematical, Physical and Engineering Sciences. Vol. 269. No. 1336. The Royal Society, 1962.
*Sachs, Rainer K. "Gravitational waves in general relativity. VIII. Waves in asymptotically flat space-time." Proceedings of the Royal Society of London A: Mathematical, Physical and Engineering Sciences. Vol. 270. No. 1340. The Royal Society, 1962.

Comment: This doesn't sound right. A super translation sounds like it should be a translation in a super direction, in the sense of supermanifolds (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermanifold).

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan I don't know what Hawking was specifically refering to, but I do know that what I said is indeed a  supertranslation. You can see also here arxiv.org/abs/1411.5745. I did not see any reference to your definition of supertranslation. The prefix "super" is overused by physicists...

Comment: This answer is my understanding as well, but if you head over to nLab (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/super-translation+group) you will see that they characterize the supertranslations as a super group translation in the sense of supermanifolds. In Hawking's paper he also mentions that "the usual time and space translations form a sub-group of the supertranslations".

Comment: I guess the take away is that asymptotically flat manifolds have additional symmetry directions, characterized by the super-directions, and black hole horizons have this feature as well.